# How to independently set a button click in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I am trying to figure out on how to set a button that can independently be disabled when using the .map function. So I created a state whenever the button is clicked, it disables that specific button. However, it only disables all of the buttons which is not what i wanted. Is there a way to make the buttons have their own click event which can be disabled according to the index?

```
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const array = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"];

  const disableClick = () => {
    setClick(true);
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {array.map((item) => (
        <div>
          <h2>{item}</h2>
          {!click ? (
            <button onClick={disableClick}>CLICK {item}</button>
          ) : (
            <button disabled>Button clicked</button>
          )}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Create a button component and put the `check` state in that component. This would ensure that every individual button have their own check property which can be manipulated from outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the  click handler and `useState` in a separate component.

```
const ButtonView = (textContent) => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  const onClick = () => {
    setDisabled(true);
  };

  if (disabled) {
    return <button disabled={disabled}>Button clicked</button>;
  }

  return <button onClick={onClick}>CLICK {textContent}</button>;
};

export const View = () => {
  const array = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"];
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {array.map((item, key) => (
        <div key={key}>
          <h2>{item}</h2>
          <ButtonView textContent={item} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Or do this:

```
const ButtonView = (textContent) => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  const onClick = () => {
    setDisabled(true);
  };
  const content = disabled ? "Button clicked" : textContent
  return <button disabled={disabled} onClick={onClick}>CLICK {content}</button>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable takes an arguments you can supply it with
`<button disabled={click? true:false} >Button clicked</button>`

> Is there a way to make the buttons have their own click event which
> can be disabled according to the index?

Yes, How? instead of setting the click state to true or false, we can set it to contain name of the button  `const [disabledBtn, setDisabledBtn] = useState("item 1");` and then we can compare it with the items from the map.
`<button disabled={disabledBtn == item ? true:false} >Button clicked</button>`

This code render the buttons with the first button disabled by default, if the user clicks on one of the other available buttons it will trigger rerender and that btn will be disabled.
You should add a key to your childern components to maintain uniqueness between renderings.

This code snippet should answer your question

```
const [disabledBtn, setDisabledBtn] = useState("item 1");
const array = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"];

const handleDisableClick = (item) => {
  setDisabledBtn(item);
};

return (
  <div className="App">
    {array.map((item, idx) => (
      <div key={idx}>
        <h2>{item}</h2>
        <button
          disabled={disabledBtn == item ? true : false}
          onClick={() => handleDisableClick(item)}
        >
          Button clicked
        </button>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Okay so I tried your code, and what I've noticed is that it acts like radio buttons except it's using actual buttons. Is there a way to make them act like checkboxes like what if I tried clicking multiple buttons at different indexes and disable them accordingly?